# Ubuntu desktop suddenly points to home folder

Tags: gnome, system

As of now, my desktop has begun showing the contents of my home folder (`~`) instead of the contents of ~/desktop. I must have changed something, but I have no idea what, or what I was doing exactly when it happened.

How do I re-point gnome to the right folder?

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If gconf doesn't work, open your home directory and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files. Look in `.config` for `user-dirs.dirs` and be sure it resembles this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Work"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Great! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I notice when I set the configs this doesn't work, but I realize may I need to reboot the computer, when I did it, the changes affect now, Thanks!

Comment: ok, reboot needed

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04, before applying this solution, I had to remove symbolic links to the Desktop and some other folders like Music, Videos, etc., and re-create them. Otherwise, it doesn't affect the situation. `rm ~/Desktop` and then `mkdir -p ~/Desktop`. Note that my Desktop folder was empty, I don't know what happens otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type/copy:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_is_home_dir false
```

You probably need to log out and back in again (alternatively, you can run `nautilus -q` to restart just Nautilus).

Comment: An upvote for the hint on `nautilus -q` =)

Comment: Much easier to do it this way.

Answer (score 7):

I think if you run this command:

```
vim ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

you'll find:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"
```

but it should have `/Desktop` like this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"/Desktop
```

So just run the command `mkdir Desktop` and then change the line in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

The other lines should look like this:

```
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Work"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>alt f2</kbd> and type `gksu gconf-editor` and navigate to `apps` -> `nautilus` -> `preferences`. Have a look at:

[image: im2]

Comment: This didn't solve my problem - the option was already set to false.

Answer (score 3):

This is what helped me

```
sudo -H gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

And replaced `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"` with `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Shouldn't need sudo and you probably don't want to risk changing ownership.  Mine is .rw------- $USER.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the ~/Desktop directory got deleted. If the folder ~/Desktop does not exist, `xdg-user-dirs-update` will change ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs entry to:

XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"

Run the following commands to fix the problem:

```
cd ~
mkdir Desktop

vi ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

And replace `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"` with `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

You will need to log out and back in again or reboot for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

This might happen after removing the desktop directory as it’s documented in [`man xdg-user-dirs-update`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdg-user-dirs-update.1.html) (grammar corrected):

> Additionally, any configured directories that point to non-existing locations are reset by pointing them to the user’s home directory.
> (…) xdg-user-dirs-update is normally run automatically at the start of a user session to update the XDG user dirs according to the user’s locale.

To reset this, you can run `xdg-user-dirs-update --force`<sup>1</sup>, then log out and in.

> Update existing user-dirs.dir, but force a full reset. This means: Don't reset nonexisting directories to HOME, rather recreate the directory.

---

<sup>1</sup> Don’t do this if you have configured some directories to point to a non-standard path. In such a case, [edit the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` manually](https://askubuntu.com/a/451343/250300).

Answer (score 1):

Some folders in my $HOME such as Desktop and Templates, were always empty and never being used, so I removed them. Then after upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, all the files and directories including the hidden ones suddenly all displayed on the desktop. As suggested, edit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs to point the XDG_DESKTOP_DIR back to "$HOME/Desktop". Of cause, do mkdir ~/Desktop, then logout and login back, voilà, everything is good!

Answer (score 0):

Following command works on Ubuntu 12.10.

```
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_is_home_dir false
```