# Desktop Icons replaced with Home folder contents

Tags: nautilus, home-directory

I have an issue where my desktop is covered with the contents of my Home folder rather than my Desktop folder.
I've tried following this post: [Ubuntu desktop suddenly points to home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44449/ubuntu-desktop-suddenly-points-to-home-folder)
but to no avail.

[image]

If anyone has any tips that would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this setting using the Dconf Editor (dconf-tools):

org > gnome > nautilus > preferences > desktop-is-home-dir

Uncheck it if it's checked.

You may need to reboot so the ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file can be rewritten and reloaded.

Comment: Thank you, it was unchecked, so I checked and unchecked it to refresh it and it worked! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen when you delete ~/Desktop directory. If this is the case just simply recreate ~/Desktop directory (or change where the XDG_DESKTOP_DIR= points in your ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file)

Answer (score 0):

With [**Ubuntu Tweak**](http://ubuntu-tweak.com), click on `Tweaks` > `Desktop Icon Settings`. Then uncheck the check box related to " *Show contents of "Home Folder"* " (the last one at the bottom).