# Why do my files and folders from home/user appear on the desktop after last update?

Tags: 18.04, updates, home-directory

Since last week's update, all the files and folders from the home directory appear on the desktop. I have done nothing to cause this as far as I know. Can anyone help me disable this "feature"?

The version of Ubuntu is 18.04 and the problem appeared only after the last update. The solution present in the other question does not solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu desktop suddenly points to home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44449/ubuntu-desktop-suddenly-points-to-home-folder)

Comment: The solution presented in this https://askubuntu.com/questions/44449/ubuntu-desktop-suddenly-points-to-home-folder did not solve the problem.       I edit   .config/user-dirs.dirs to write: 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
but on every reboot, the file gets automaticaly to XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/".
If i mkae ls home/user/Desktop is gives: impossible to access the /home/user/Desktop: too many levels of symbolic links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the directory `Desktop` and made a new empty one. Then I edited `.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

Rebooted and this solved the problem.