# user-dirs.dir Contents Corruption

Tags: boot, gnome, 20.04

I am having a problem where the Gnome configuration file `~/.config/user-dir.dir` is being modified at boot time to point to `$HOME/` folder instead of `$HOME/Desktop` for the `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` entry. The result is that I always get the contents of the home directory displayed on my desktop at boot time. I want to find out how I can suppress this behavior.

I suspect it happened because my 4 years old grand-daughter was playing with the keyboard so anything might have been entered. I only want to fix the problem and I am not particularly interested in why it happened.

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.

Comment: Check whether the folder "$HOME/Desktop" exists with exactly that name. If a non existing "Desktop" is not the issue, try resetting with the command `xdg-user-dirs-update --force`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu desktop suddenly points to home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44449/ubuntu-desktop-suddenly-points-to-home-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on so I will list some information on this hoping I can the problem you face:

- The file is `user-dirs.dirs`
- Permissions should be `-rw-------` (so `chmod 600 user-dirs.dirs)`
- The owner and group need to be your user (so `chown $USER:$USER user-dirs.dirs`)
- Mind that in Linux Desktop is not the same as desktop
- In `/etc/xdg/` there is a default file in case you need to restore it of view how it should look like ( `xdg-user-dirs-update --force` resets your local version)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the directory `$HOME/Desktop` had been deleted somehow and I did not notice. Recreating the directory fixed the problem.