# Desktop splayed with hundreds of icons

Tags: bug-reporting

After restarting Ubuntu due to the pc crashing, I randomly see this:

[image]

The entire desktop is covered in icons. I cannot see them in the Desktop folder, nor move them around.

Here is the output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

```
> xander@xander:~$ cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
> # This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
> # If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
> # interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
> # Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
> # homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
> # absolute path. No other format is supported.
> #  XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/" XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads" XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates" XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
> XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents" XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
> XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures" XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Is this a bug? What can I do?

I have this system:
[image]

Comment: Those seems like contents of $HOME folder. Did you delete Desktop folder?

Comment: I saw it a moment ago, but now it doesn't show up in the search.

Comment: Do I just create a new desktop folder?

Comment: Yes. Also, please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Comment: ok, done. I created a new Desktop folder (it somehow moved into the downloads folder). But after restarting I can still see the home files on the desktop.

Comment: Run `nano ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and fix the value of `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` to `$HOME/Desktop`. Restart the session/gnome-shell.

Comment: Ok that fixed it, thanks. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/44449/ubuntu-desktop-suddenly-points-to-home-folder.