# Home directroy files displayed in Desktop

Tags: gnome, 20.04, nautilus, desktop-icons

For a presentation I had to temprorary clear my Desktop , so I ran 
`mv Desktop Desktop1` 
after which desktop was cleared

But after a reboot my HOME directory files started to appear in Desktop
I tried to run 
`mv Desktop1 Desktop` 
and restarted the PC yet the problem wasn't solved

I also noticed that the Desktop shortcut in Nautilus File manager's side panel too disappeared

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: `$HOME` is now your desktop dir because you renamed the "normal" Desktop dir. Check `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` if this is true, and change it back. Then restart.

Comment: @plumo yes it worked , I changed the directory to which DESKTOP was pointing to

Comment: @nobody yes looks like this question's solution mathces with soln in https://askubuntu.com/questions/44449/ubuntu-desktop-suddenly-points-to-home-folder