# Empty XDG user directories turn into symbolic links

Tags: home-directory, symbolic-link, 23.04, xdg, 23.10

For some reasons, when an XDG user directory (i.e., `Desktop`, `Downloads`, `Templates`, `Public`, `Documents`, `Music`, `Pictures`, or `Videos`) is empty, it turns into a symbolic link after some time. Below is an example when it happens to `Downloads`.

```
toto@pc-toto:~$ ls -l
total 60K
drwxrwxr-x  3 toto toto 4.0K Aug 31 10:10  Desktop/
drwxr-xr-x  5 toto toto 4.0K Aug 11 13:52  Documents/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 toto toto   21 Aug 31 10:51  Downloads -> /home/toto/Downloads
drwxr-xr-x  7 toto toto 4.0K Aug  3 16:50  Music/
drwxr-xr-x 26 toto toto 4.0K Aug  3 16:53  Pictures/
drwx------ 11 toto toto 4.0K Aug  9 11:34  snap/
drwxr-xr-x  5 toto toto 4.0K Aug  3 16:55  Videos/
toto@pc-toto:~$
```

This started to happen a few days ago on Ubuntu 23.04. It has also been seen on Ubuntu 20.04: [Home directories turned into symbolic links without telling me the reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482903/home-directories-turned-into-symbolic-links-without-telling-me-the-reason).

The empty folders will turn into symbolic links in a matter of hours. I didn't find any reason for this.

EDIT: The problem is still going on after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10.

#### Temporary solution

Delete the symbolic link and recreate the relevant directories.

```
toto@pc-toto:~$ rm Downloads 
rm: remove symbolic link 'Downloads'? y
toto@pc-toto:~$ mkdir Downloads
toto@pc-toto:~$ ls -l
total 64K
drwxrwxr-x  3 toto toto 4.0K Aug 31 10:10  Desktop/
drwxr-xr-x  5 toto toto 4.0K Aug 11 13:52  Documents/
drwxr-xr-x  2 toto toto 4.0K Aug 31 10:51  Downloads/
drwxr-xr-x  7 toto toto 4.0K Aug  3 16:50  Music/
drwxr-xr-x 26 toto toto 4.0K Aug  3 16:53  Pictures/
drwx------ 11 toto toto 4.0K Aug  9 11:34  snap/
drwxr-xr-x  5 toto toto 4.0K Aug  3 16:55  Videos/
toto@pc-toto:~$
```

Then, add a hidden file in each directories. This would prevent the directories to become empty and to turn into symbolic links.

```
toto@pc-toto:~$ cd Downloads 
toto@pc-toto:~/Downloads$ touch .empty_file
toto@pc-toto:~/Downloads$
```

Finally, edit the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to put the right paths of XDG directories back. For example, replace `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"` by `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"`.
*Note: Since the appearance of the symbolic links, this file won't be affected until you reboot.*

Comment: Upvote because your question is clear and well documented. I cannot imagine how something like this could proceed automatically, though.

Comment: And yet it does happen automatically.

Comment: I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10. The problem is still going on.