# Standard user directories are replaced by broken symbolic links

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, home-directory

I have a very strange problem on Ubuntu 20.04.
Recently, occasionally some of the standard user directories (Downloads, Music, Public, Templates) disappear and are replaced by broken symbolic links to themselves.
I can't associate it with using a new package/application.
The directories also disappear from the user-dirs.dirs file:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"  
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"  
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"  
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"  
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"  
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"  
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"  
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Results of `ls -alh` :

[image: ls -alh screenshot]

[update]
I finally discovered the culprit - Okular. Every time I open a document it deletes some of the standard directories and replaces them with broken symbolic links.

Comment: Create the directories again and repair the user-dirs.dirs file. Not sure what could have caused this.

Comment: @vanadium, thanks for the reply! Done that several times already, it happens repeatedly. The working hypothesis this is the anti-virus, but no actual evidence for that. Trying to monitor the directories with inotifywait. Weird problem.

Comment: Yes, I suffer from the same problem. Okular? Yes, I actually used it recently. It makes sense. Thank you for the hint! (what an obnoxious bug!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Home directories turned into symbolic links without telling me the reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482903/home-directories-turned-into-symbolic-links-without-telling-me-the-reason)