# Question about getting the file permission

Tags: 20.04

I am new here and i tried looking for the solution but i couldn't find it
I am couldn't open Public videos or Templates(there are also red in the terminal)
Thanks
I tried solving it by using Chmod but didn't help
I even ignored the problem now my vlc doesn't open( i tried installing it by the portal and app store but no help)
https://imgur.com/7CW9tiZ
https://imgur.com/QGdnS5m
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4dqy.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehYcG.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/QGdnS5m
https://imgur.com/7CW9tiZ

Comment: Those look like broken symbolic links (pointing to themselves) - see for example [Standard user directories are replaced by broken symbolic links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488535/standard-user-directories-are-replaced-by-broken-symbolic-links)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.